# Why mysqli_connect() must receive the password parameter with no encryption?

Tags: php, mysql, encryption, mysqli

I created a user to use my database

```
CREATE USER 'my_user'@'localhost' IDENTIFIED BY 'my_pass';
GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON * . * TO 'my_user'@'localhost';
FLUSH PRIVILEGES;
```

The pass was stored in encrypted mode on the *mysql.user* table.

But when i use the mysqli_connect() method, I find that when I give the pass as parameter, I must give the non-encrypted, original value that I used on the query if I don´t want to get the famous "Connect failed: Access denied for user 'my_user'@'localhost' (using password: YES)".

But that is actually a different string value that the one stored on the database (encrypted version).

How is it? Would not be more secure to give as parameter the encrypted version in case someone access the .PHP file where I establish the connection? Why mysqli_connection doesn´t accept it? Is there a way to do it?

Comment: when you log in to stackoverflow or any other site-- you give your plain text passowrd - but they are stored hashed. they are hashed in case the db that holds them is compromised.

Comment: Why would it be more secure? You would still be able to log in with the password found in the php file

Comment: what's the point in the encrypted password if it can be used as well as a plain one? If your imaginary mysqli_connect would accept an encrypted password, then all you need is to peek into a PHP file, get that encrupted password and connect to a database. WHAT GIVES?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You as a user don't know how the password is encrypted (it's actually not encrypted at all, but hashed).

You just pass the password, and MySQL can perform the same hashing as on the original password and compare it to what is stored. If you pass the hashed version, the whole benefit of hashing is gone: If somebody gets the hashes from the server, they can just use those to log in as if they were normal passwords. The hash has then become the password.

Added benefit is that MySQL, because it has the original password, could re-hash it with a better algorithm, add a bit of salt and store that improved version. If it never gets the original, that can't be done. [PHP's password functions](http://php.net/manual/en/ref.password.php) support this as well. You can check with `password_needs_rehash` if a hashed password is still hashed properly, and update your database if it isn't.

So, for security, you will need to take other measures. These are at least:

- Store the password in an include file that lives outside of the document root. That way, nobody can open that file directly.
- You can prevent include files to be opened without being included (for instance by checking for a define that was set in index.php). That's nice, but if PHP fails due to a configuration error, people can just browse the file's source, so stick the the previous rule.
- Always make a special database user. Don't use `root`. Give this user just enough right to operate the database, but no more. No rights to drop tables for instance.
- Always give that user a unique password. You don't have to remember this password. Just generate random garbage with plenty of characters.
- Change the password regularly. Maybe you could even script that and store the updated password in the config.

Comment: I guess I am newbie and I don´t know how to make some of these things yet. For example, the first one (storing password in a file outside the root and then include it). But I will keep it in mind and learn about it. Thanks for such a useful information.

Comment: The first one is relatively simple. For instance, when you browse to yourdomain/index.php, it uses `/var/www/public-html/index.php`, which means that `/var/www/public-html` is the 'root' of what is publicly visible. `index.php` can `include '/var/www/config.php'` or `include '../config.php`. That file is one level up from the (public) root, so people can't navigate to it. But anyway, that's a bit aside of this Q&A. I'm sure you can find better sources, but I hope I put you on the right track.

Comment: Yes of course @GolezTrol, it was very hepful for me and puts me on the right way! Million Thanks!